# how to have multiple labels in table cell without making custom table view iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

i have a not custom table view view that i mean that i'm using the cellForRowAtIndexPath. I want my cell to have 2 labels one for a title and the other for a date. I have tried to use this code that doesn't work:

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 109.0f); 

    UIView* view = cell.contentView;
    UILabel* labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    UILabel* labelDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];

    [cell addSubview:labelTitle];
    [cell addSubview:labelDate];

    cell.labelDate.text = @"title";
    cell.labelTitle.text = @"date";
```

I get an error saying: `Property 'labelDate' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'`

So it seems that the cell doesn't recognize my labels. Can thsi be done in some way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:title];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use table view delegate methods as;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *detailField_Name = [[NSString alloc] init];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = @"title";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"date";

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7) is a good example from Apple how to make some custom cells.

Answer (score 0):

use

> [cell.contentView addSubview:title];

instead of

> [cell addSubview:labelTitle];

and

> labelDate.text = @"title";

instead of

> cell.labelDate.text = @"title";

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple label in below way:

UILabel *lblTaskTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45.0, 5, 100.0, 35.0)];

```
    [lblTaskTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0]];        
    [lblTaskTitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [lblTaskTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    lblTaskTitle.text = oTaskType.taskTypeTitle;
    [cell addSubview:lblTaskTitle];
```

UILabel *lblTaskDetail = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45.0, 5, 140.0, 35.0)];

```
    [lblTaskDetail setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0]];       
    [lblTaskDetail setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [lblTaskDetail setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    lblTaskDetail.text = oTaskType.taskTypeTitle;
    [cell addSubview:lblTaskDetail];
```

Let me know in case of any difficulty.